# Broken USB port slows down initialization of another port

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, nixos

## Question

How can I prevent Linux from trying to activate a broken USB port on my motherboard?

## Overview

I have a broken USB port on my motherboard (also nothing is plugged into it):

> usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71

This (usb 1-3) port blocks usb 1-4 port from initalizing until the system gives up on it. To clarfy, according to dmesg my ports are usually initalized in this order:

```
usb 5-1:    available instantly       [USB2.0 Hub] (motherboard)
usb 3-1:    available instantly       [Generic USB Multimedia Keyboard] (frontside of PC)
usb 1-1:    available instantly       [Razer Goliathus Extended Chroma Mousepad] (motherboard)
usb 3-2:    available instantly       [FREE] (frontside of PC)
usb 3-4:    available instantly       [AURA LED Controller] (internal)
usb 5-3:    available instantly       [FREE] (motherboard)
usb 5-4:    available instantly       [FREE] (motherboard)
usb 5-1.2: available instantly       [Razer Basilisk Ultimate Dongle] (motherboard)
usb 5-1.3: available instantly       [Razer Mouse Dock] (motherboard)
usb 1-3:    -BROKEN PORT-            [FREE] (motherboard)
usb 1-4:    10s initalization delay [Razer Huntsman Elite] (motherboard)
```

If I plug my keyboard (Razer Huntsman Elite) into usb 1-4 port I have to wait 10 seconds after reaching tty0 before it starts responding to keystrokes. Furthermore keystrokes to usb 1-4 aren't registered if USB Power Managment isn't disabled *(usbcore.autosuspend=-1)*. The keyboard works instantly with any other port (5-1 / 3-1 / 1-1 / 3-2 / 5-3 / 5-4).

**usb 1-4 port becomes available only after usb 1-3 port stops enumerating (when this message pops up in tty0):**

> usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device

## Logs

journalctl -b
https://pastebin.com/raw/f9Brfzt3

dmesg
https://pastebin.com/raw/H6Wm2v5M

## What I've tried

I can't disable the broken port with this udev rule as it's not available in the first place:

```
$ echo '1-3' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
1-3
tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind: No such device
```

---

#### Workaround 1:

Plugging the keyboard in any port except for usb 1-4 and usb 1-3.

#### Workaround 2:

Using *usbcore.autosuspend=-1* and waiting 10 seconds allows me to use usb 1-4.

#### Notes:

usb 1-4 works immediately in:

- [GRUB2].
- [BIOS].
- [Windows Bootloader].
- [Windows 11].

usb 1-4 works 10 seconds after reaching tty0 if USB Power Managment is disabled with:

- [SystemD] NixOS 23.05pre454549.545c7a31e5d (kernel 6.1.11 & 5.15.93 & 5.10.167).
- [SystemD] Debian 12 Bookworm (kernel 6.1.0).
- [SystemD] PopOS 22.04 LTS (kernel 6.0.12).

usb 1-4 works in tty0 for 2 seconds in:

- [OpenRC] Alpine Linux Extended v3.17 (kernel 5.15.93).

Other things I've tried out of curiosity:

- [BIOS] Updating to latest BIOS in my X570-E Gaming motherboard (ComboV2PI 1208)
- [BIOS] Disabling xHCI handoff
- [BIOS] Disabling IOMMU in BIOS (iommu=soft kernel parameter didn't make a different either)
- [BIOS] Disabling fast boot

Comment: other attempts: if the port is on a hub that supports `uhubctl` (that's not very common) you can try to selectively disable this port. If if's mostly a software issue rather than also hardware, you can de-authorize it (write 0 to its /sys usb authorized entry instead of trying to unbind it).

Comment: Thanks for these ideas! Looks like my motherboard doesn't support uhubctl and the broken port doesn't actually show up in /sys/bus/usb/devices/. I'm surprised I can't find a kernel parameter to ignore this port completely huh..